# How can I run multiple jobs from a large queue at the same time in Perl?

Tags: perl, unix, lsf

I would like to program job limits for the [LSF command](http://publibfp.dhe.ibm.com/epubs/pdf/c2753053.pdf) [`bsub`](http://www.vub.ac.be/BFUCC/LSF/bsub.1.html) into my Perl script which launches LSF jobs under the hood. If I have something like 2000 jobs, I would like to run at most 20 jobs at any given time. I have seen scripts that launch 20 jobs and then wait for them all to finish before launching another 20.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Several existing Perl modules, including [`Parallel::ForkManager`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Parallel::ForkManager) and [`Forks::Super`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Forks::Super) (of which I am the author) offer this functionality.

There is also an [`LSF::JobManager`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LSF::JobManager) module that I don't know anything else about.

---

Parallel::ForkManager skeleton

```
use Parallel::ForkManager;
$pm = new Parallel::ForkManager(20);
foreach $job (@jobsToRun) {
    $pm->start and next;
    system("bsub -K $job");  # bsub -K job  to wait until job finishes, right?
    $pm->finish;
}
```

---

And in Forks::Super

```
use Forks::Super MAX_PROC => 20;
foreach $job (@jobsToRun) {
    fork { cmd => "bsub -K $job" };
}
```

---

Comment: After all these years of using LSF, I just now learned about `bsub -K`. Thanks!